# QFontMetric.width() returns smaller width

Tags: qt, user-interface, fonts, cross-platform

This code is supposed to set the width of `QTextEdit heading` to the width of the text contained in it:

```
heading->setText("Clipboard: ");
heading->setFixedWidth(QFontMetrics(heading->font()).width("Clipboard: "));
```

But the actual width is a bit smaller as you can see:

[image]

I've tried

```
heading->setFixedWidth(QFontMetrics(heading->font()).boundingRect("Clipboard: ").width());
```

but the result is same. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try with; `heading->setFixedWidth(heading->verticalScrollBar()->height() + QFontMetrics(heading->font()).width("Clipboard:"));`

Comment: @eyllanesc shouldn't it be `heading->setFixedWidth(heading->verticalScrollBar()->width(‌​) + QFontMetrics(heading->font()).width("Clipboard:"));`?